# 27 Lines on a Cubic

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

In Ravi Vakil's notes, there is a proof (in section 27, of course) of the famous result that every nonsingular cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3_k$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ has exactly 27 lines.

In the proof, we set up an incidence correspondence in Exercise 27.3.A, show that it is an 19-dimensional irreducible nonsingular variety, then use the facts about dimensions of fibers in Exercise 27.3.B to show that every cubic has a line, and that a dense open subset of the space of cubics have only finitely many lines on them.

Then in 27.3.2, the proof that there are 27 lines on every nonsingular cubic surfaces, it says that $\pi$ (the map from our incidence correspondence to the space of cubics) has dimension 0 over the entire locus of nonsingular cubics.

But it seems based off the exercise that we should only be able to conclude that $\pi$ is of dimension 0 over a dense open subset of the set of nonsingular cubics.  What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, the argument does not stop there. So far you know only that $\pi$ is a finite morphism. Vakil proves also that it is flat and unramified (hence etale). Then since we have an example of a cubic surface having exactly 27 lines on it (Fermat cubic), you know that each fiber of $\pi$ is a nonreduced scheme consisting of 27 points and you are done.